# Is there a memory leak in my script or is it another culprit?

Tags: php, linux, apache, codeigniter, memory-leaks

I recently switched from a shared to dedicated host giving me alot more monitoring/control. I've been trying to debug an issue I've had since before I switched, very high memory usage. I think I've narrowed it down to a specific script that is a subscription to an instagram feed/api. It works in a codeIgniter framework.

This is a screenshot of my processes. Note the really high httpd memory values
[image]

Here's my controller in codeIgniter

```
class Subscribe extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->instagram_api->access_token = 'hidden';
    }
    function callback()
    {

    //echo anchor('logs/activity.log', 'LOG');
$min_id = ''; 
$next_min_id = '';      

$this->load->model('Subscribe_model');
$min_id = $this->Subscribe_model->min_id();

echo $min_id;

    $pugs = $this->instagram_api->tagsRecent('tagg','',$min_id);
    if($pugs){
    if (property_exists($pugs->pagination, 'min_tag_id')) {
            $next_min_id = $pugs->pagination->min_tag_id;
        }   
    foreach($pugs as $pug) {
        if(is_array($pug)) {     
            foreach($pug as $media) { 
                $url = $media->images->standard_resolution->url;
                $m_id = $media->id;
                $c_time = $media->created_time;
                $user = $media->user->username;
                $filter = $media->filter;
                $comments = $media->comments->count;
                $caption = $media->caption->text;
                $link = $media->link;
                $low_res=$media->images->low_resolution->url;
                $thumb=$media->images->thumbnail->url;
                $lat = $media->location->latitude;
                $long = $media->location->longitude;
                $loc_id = $media->location->id;
                $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));

                $data = array(
                   'media_id' => $m_id,
                   'min_id' => $next_min_id,
                   'url' => $url, 
                   'c_time' => $c_time,
                   'user' => $user,
                   'filter' => $filter,
                   'comment_count' => $comments,
                   'caption' => $caption,
                   'link' => $link, 
                   'low_res' => $low_res,
                   'thumb' => $thumb,
                   'lat' => $lat,
                   'long' => $long,
                   'loc_id' => $loc_id,
                );
                $this->Subscribe_model->add_pug($data);

            }

        }

    }
    }
```

and here is the model....

```
class Subscribe_model extends CI_Model {

    function min_id(){

        $this->db->order_by("c_time", "desc");      
        $query = $this->db->get("pugs");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
           $row = $query->row(); 
           $min_id = $row->min_id;
           if(!$min_id){
            $min_id ='';
           }
        }   

        return $min_id;

    }

    function add_pug($data){

        $query = $this->db->get_where('pugs', array('media_id'=>$data['media_id']));
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return FALSE;   
        }else{
            $this->db->insert('pugs', $data);   
        }

    }
}
```

//============================EDIT========================//

I've converted some of the services over to fast-cgi and it seems to have brought my memory usage down significantly but I've noticed a bump in CPU. I was hoping that switching to a dedicated server would have far less headaches and make things much easier but it's been a nightmare so far. Affraid I've bit off more than I can chew.

Another fear of mine is adding some more domain names to the server. Will that add a new process that will run real high like the multiple php-cgi's running in the last image?

Here's my most recent outputs...
[image]
[image]

Comment: What distribution of Linux are using? If CentOS then httpd by default is not configured to use workers, also PHP has this issue anyway, consider using FastCGI?

Comment: Is switching servers an option? I've heard good things about nginx and php-fpm.

Comment: No I just set up the server. @Devraj ~It's a mediatemple DV server. CentOS 5 and Linux 2.6.18-028stab099.3

Comment: @GThompson try something on these lines, http://www.thomasnetworks.net/2011/06/setting-up-apache-2-mpm-mod_fcgi-php-apc-on-centos-5-5/

Comment: i dont think it is memory leakage; both php and apache are Very sturdy and relase their memory usage (allthough keeping references untill asked to release them) after each request is processed. Once OOP is brought to PHP the usage grows faster though.. But you should not be concerned - unless you lease a host with only 256MB ram assigned or similar. Adding domains is (or should be anyways) done by 'virtual' mapping, so no - it will not introduce more processes. Instead control the Maximum processes via httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

To ensure there is no true memory leakage, try having nothing but the httpd/myslqd running on the server (killall Xorg / telinit 3) and then stop the mentioned two services. Note down output from `free|grep Mem |sed 's/\([^0-9]*[^\ ]*\)\{3\}\([^\ ]*\).*/\1/'`. This is X free bytes of RAM. Now, start httpd/mysqld services and let them run for a few hundred requests. Stop the services and note down numbers again, repeat until satisfied with median results.

It is not uncommon for httpd to consume a lot of RAM. Also mysqld caches in-memory. This is simply because, if the same request is encountered consequtive times (in a row) then the static caches are allready buffered and good-to-go.

For PHP a Class is pre-compiled and once the system needs it after first compile, it will not have to interpret the script line-by-line, it will have a bytecode encoded object to work with. The compilation is off course recompiled if fstat.mtime > bytecode.mtime..

You can analyse real-memory usage the non-swapped kind with this command:

```
ps -ylC httpd --sort:rss
```

Child process size for serving static file is about 2-3M. For dynamic content such as PHP, it may be around 15M

To configure how apache sets up the workers, these parameters are valid in a httpd.conf:

```
StartServers, 
MaxClients, 
MinSpareThreads, 
MaxSpareThreads, 
ThreadsPerChild, 
MaxRequestsPerChild
```

Check this link: http://www.howtoforge.com/configuring_apache_for_maximum_performance

> Section 3.5:
>
> The MaxClients sets the limit on maximum simultaneous requests that
> can be supported by the server. No more than this much number of child
> processes are spawned. It shouldn't be set too low such that new
> connections are put in queue, which eventually time-out and the server
> resources are left unused. Setting this too high will cause the server
> to start swapping and the response time will degrade drastically.
> Appropriate value for MaxClients can be calculated as: MaxClients =
> Total RAM dedicated to the web server / Max child process size

Apache performance tuning is available here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html, skip down to section about Process creation for more info on above mentioned config options.